# Is there a way to transform objects that spring data repositories return?

Tags: jpa, spring-data

Right now I have an entity object and a DTO. The repository returns a list of objects arrays when I do a simple example like: findById(). Is there a way to easily map the return type to be a custom DTO object rather than always return entity objects?

Example is below:

```
@Query("Select f.id, f.name from Food f where f.id = :id")
public List<Object[]> findById(@Param("id") String id);
```

My DTO object looks like:

```
FoodDto{
    private String id;
    private String name;
}
```

Right now I've only ever been able to get repositories to return a List< Object[] > type.

Answer (score 20):

Try this.

```
@Query("Select new package.FoodDto(f.id, f.name) from Food f where f.id = :id")
public List<FoodDto> findById(@Param("id") String id);
```

Assuming class FoodDto is in package, if not you need to set the full package.

Also I assume the FoodDto have a constructor that match

```
public FoodDto(int id, String name){
 //Variable assignation
}
```

I never tried in spring-jpa but that works in JPQL so I assume it will work XD

Comment: throws exception `ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected` on returning DTO from a nativeQuery.

Comment: paste your query here

Comment: spring jpa doesnt support constructors in a nativequery afaik

Comment: yes you are right, this feature is just only available under JPQL context

Comment: '@Query("Select new package.FoodDto(f.id, new package.OtherDto(f.name)) from Food f where f.id = :id")' can i write something like this?

Comment: I think you could, try and let us know