# Spring Data map results

Tags: spring-data

I use Spring Data and I can't find a way to map a @Query results into a DTO. E.g on the query

```
@Query("select f.a f.b from Foo f")
List<FooStripped> find();
```

where

```
public class FooStripped {
   String a;
   String b;
   ...
}
```

I want all the results to be mapped to a list of FooStripped an Object[] is returned.

Answer (score 2):

You can see an example for this in [Is there a way to transform objects that spring data repositories return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22360744/is-there-a-way-to-transform-objects-that-spring-data-repositories-return)

But I would not do that to be honest. I would advice you do to this manually in the service/controller level. You can use for this the following framework http://modelmapper.org/ or any other object mapping framework.