# How can transform objects that spring data repositories return?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22360744/is-there-a-way-to-transform-objects-that-spring-data-repositories-return/22368391#22368391?newreg=10f1f2d356c14736bfb8996bf0963bb7)
and I have similar problem, but I would like to get only two from four fields - for example: only id and name from id, name, dateOfBirth, weight.

```
 public interface ICatDAO extends CrudRepository<Cat,Long> {

     @Query(value = "SELECT c.id, c.name FROM Cat c")
     public List<Cat> findAll(); 
     //...
 }
```

If I use query: `@Query(value = "SELECT c FROM Cat c")` I get objects list type 'Cat', but with all fields.

If I use query: `@Query(value = "SELECT c.id, c.name FROM Cat c")` I get object list type 'Object' and this is the problem. What should I do in this case?

Comment: Did you try the suggested answer from the question your refer to? Namely defining a DTO and using it in the query. Your DTO will have two fields id, and name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use [DTO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22368391) is suggested.

Create your `CatDto`:

```java
public class CatDto {
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    public CatDto(Long id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
    // getters, setters and other stuff you need 
}
```

Then edit you repo:

```
public interface CatRepo extends CrudRepository<Cat,Long> {

    //...
    @Query("select new ...CatDto(c.id, c.name) from Cat c")
    public List<CatDto> getCatDtos(); 
}
```

And you will get a list of your `CatDto`.

`...CatDto(...)` - is a [fully qualified name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_name) of your `CatDto` constructor. For examlpe `com.example.mycatproject.domain.CatDto`.

Another approach is to use '[projection](https://spring.io/blog/2016/05/03/what-s-new-in-spring-data-hopper#projections-on-repository-query-methods)' interface for DTO:

```java
public interface CatDto {
    Long getId();
    String getName();
}

public interface CatRepo extends CrudRepository<Cat,Long> {

    //...
    @Query("select c.id as id, c.name as name from Cat c")
    public List<CatDto> getCatDtos(); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! :)
I am a beginner in learning spring-data-jpa and I didn't think that DTO is so open-ended - I can use it with several fields of my class and always when I need it. Wow! It's really good!

Comment: @JustynaDamarisBinięda Your welcome! )) If an answer was really helpful don't forget to upvote it...